# What should I do if I want to add module in a started spring boot program?

Tags: spring-boot

I can initialize a spring boot project with initializr in idea, but what should i do if i want to add a new module. For example: I select web moduel first. And letter I want to add mybatis in the project.

Comment: Just add the dependency to the `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @M.Deinum OP I believe , is trying to understand how to add a new module to a project , not inter-module dependency

Comment: No he doesn't. Modules relates to modules in Spring Initializer in this question, which translates to dependencies in your build file. I also nowhere mention inter-module dependencies only adding a dependency to mybatis (which is what the question is about).

Comment: @M.Deinum Oops you are right

Answer (score -1):

You can add new module to your project in IntelliJ by

```
right-clicking your project -> New-> Module
```

You can follow this link
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#multimodule-projects

This will create a new module and also add your module to the settings.gradle file making it a multi module project

Comment: How would adding a module lead to adding a dependency in your pom? Which is what the question is actually about.

Comment: I dont think so , he wanted to know how to add a new module in Idea Intellij

Comment: No he doesn't. He talks about modules in the sense of spring initializer and the question has no mention of Intellij whatsoever.